# Error:Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

Tags: android, build.gradle, number-crunching

i have tried my best ever i could i apply various methods given by other user on stackoverflow but none of this work for me

```
Error:Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
    > Error: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integrate this code in

> gradle.properties

```
android.buildCacheDir=D:/android-studio/build-cache
```

in somecase if you have tried to change the extension in android for images then undo that it may solve your problems